# Intermediate Tables & Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm kind of new to the Eloquent (Pivot / Intermediate Tables) idea.

I am using Laravel 5.3 and the docs are making a little sense, but not enough. Unfortunatley!

I have a few scenarios that I'd like to try get data from...

I have the following DB Tables

- Companies
- Company_Offers
- Offers
- Company_Attributes
- Attributes

In my scenarios the following is said of these DB Tables...

A company can have **many** offers

A company can have **many** attributes

An Offer can be associated with many companies

An attribute can be associated with many companies

I have created the 5 models to correspond to the 5 DB Tables.

I am trying to work out, How I get these relationships into my models?

Thank You!

Comment: I suggest you check out Jeffrey Ways tutorial about relationships https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/14. There are plenty other tutorials and the laravel 5 documentation is also great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `belongsToMany` relationship. For example:

```
class Company extends Model
{
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(App\Offer::class);
    }   
}
```

If you have setup your pivot table with `company_id` and `offer_id` this relationship will work automatically, and a pivot table of company_offer (singular version of model name in alphabetical order). If you didn't follow the naming convention you can specify the pivot table and foreign keys like so:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer', 'Company_Offers', 'Company_ID', 'Offer_ID');
```

Comment: Excellent answer sir! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Actually in laravel you don't have to create models for pivot tables. So you are down to three models that will look more less like this:

```
<?php
/* /app/Company.php */
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    /**
     * The offers that belong to the company.
     */
    public function offers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Offer');
    }

     /**
     * The attributes that belong to the user.
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Attribute');
    }
}


<?php
/* /app/Offer.php */
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Offer extends Model
{

    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
    }
}

<?php
/* /app/Attribute.php */
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attribute extends Model
{
    public function companies()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Company');
    }
}
```

More on how to use it to select or update those relations you can find here:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many